# How do I catch a connection failure to a nonexistant Rose::DB database?

Tags: database, perl, try-catch

My Perl application uses Rose::DB, Rose::DB::Object (ORM) and Tk on Windows XP. I need to check whether the database connection information (host, port, database name, user, password) leads to a valid connection. If I call `$db->connect` and use e.g. a nonexistant host for testing, Rose::DB says:

`DBI connect('dbname=my_db;host=192.168.70.85;port=5432','postgres',...) failed: 
could not connect to server: No route to host (0x00002751/10065)`

How do I catch this and create a new message for my application? Is this a question about try/catch in general?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You could use [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try) and do something like `try { $db->connect } catch( $e ) { say "Error connecting: $e" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution that seems to work so far was posted to me from John:

`my $ok = eval { $db->connect };`

```
if(!$ok || $@) { # Connection failed }
```